# Is there a way to disable foreign key checks? -Medoo

Tags: medoo

I am trying to remove some rows in my tables that are constrained by foreign keys. Is there a way to disable foreign key checks to allow the deletion of these items? Possibly through Medoo::raw() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys can be disabled by putting `$database->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');` before your normal Medoo statement. Don't forget to run `$database->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');` after you are finished with the need to disable.